# Pentaho Reporting Module: cannot publish the report on server

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I have the error that I can't publish reports on pentaho.
The full log you can find it here: http://pastebin.com/7yU6Dz8x

The error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.util.PublishException: The File exists and override has not been specified.

What am I missing? I am using latest Pentaho CE, and the data source of the report is a mondrian scheme. (MDX Query)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the upload of the report from pentaho web interface.

Comment: Hi, Im getting the exact same error, can you elaborate on the solution